# How to sort ArrayList of DateTime objects in descending order?

Tags: c#

How do I sort ArrayList of DateTime objects in descending order?

Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, unless you are stuck with using framework 1.1, you should not be using an `ArrayList` at all. You should use a strongly typed generic `List<DateTime>` instead.

For custom sorting there is an overload of the `Sort` method that takes a comparer. By reversing the regular comparison you get a sort in descending order:

```
list.Sort(delegate(DateTime x, DateTime y){ return y.CompareTo(x); });
```

#### Update:

With lambda expressions in C# 3, the delegate is easier to create:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
```

Answer (score 16):

As "Guffa" already said, you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` unless you are in .NET 1.1; here's a simpler `List<DateTime>` example, though:

```
List<DateTime> dates = ... // init and fill
dates.Sort();
dates.Reverse();
```

Your dates are now sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DateTime Comparer that sorts in reverse. Call Sort.

```
public class ReverseDateComparer:IComparer{ 
    public int  Compare(object x, object y){
        return -1 * DateTime.Compare(x, y);
    }
}

list.Sort(new ReverseDateComparer());
```

Comment: ...and moderately more efficient (avoids the multiply per comparison).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5:

```
// ArrayList dates = ...
var sortedDates = dates.OrderByDescending(x => x);
// test it
foreach(DateTime dateTime in sortedDates)
  Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Comment: From ArrayList you'd need a Cast<DateTime>() in there too.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<T>.Sort(YourDateTimeComparer) where YourDateTimeComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
```

Here is an example of custom IComparer use: [How to remove duplicates from int[][]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701707/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-int)