# How to sort date numerically

Tags: c#, datetime, sorting

I want to sort some dates numerically (not Date.compare())

Into what type should I convert the dates, so I could sort a table **on client side (JS)**?

int? timestamp?

and how?

Comment: What do you mean by "numerically"? Can you give a few examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Ticks` it is of `long` type.

Comment: I'd be careful with this. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx -- *It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.*

Comment: Ticks represents DateTime value. And actually Ticks used to compare dates. See Equals or CompareTo implementations.

Comment: @Yuck DateTime doesn't handle leap seconds at all, so I don't see why you'd want to take them into account when sorting.

Comment: Downvoter, it would be great to see what is wrong with my answer, please add some comments - it may be usefull to me and other users

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Ticks property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) to get a numerical representation of a DateTime. Here's a sample program that sorts them by Ticks:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime> { new DateTime(2011, 5, 31), new DateTime(2012, 7, 31), new DateTime(2010, 1, 31) };
        dates.OrderBy(d => d.Ticks).ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.ToString()));

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

which produces this output:

```
1/31/2010 12:00:00 AM
5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM
7/31/2012 12:00:00 AM
Press ENTER to exit...
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to covert date to anything to sort it:

```
new[] { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) }.OrderBy(d => d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort it like this

```
Array.Sort(datetimearr[]);
```

Use this [How to sort ArrayList of DateTime objects in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844251/how-to-sort-arraylist-of-datetime-objects-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 0):

Just add them to a collection based on `IEnumerable<DateTime>` and use **LINQ** to sort them, something like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq

...

List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 04, 01));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 04, 05));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 04, 04));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 04, 02));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 04, 03));

List<DateTime> orderedDates = dates.OrderBy(d => d);
```

You shouldn't need to use `DateTime.Ticks` as dates are comparible.